# How to prevent bots from checking out on my website

Tags: python, websites

I am developing a website to sell a product that is very likely to be botted. The reason people will bot it is not to spam me or anything, but because they want to buy the product faster than anyone else.

My current strategy has been to lock my purchase page behind a password page. Then, when I release some stock I will reveal the password via Twitter and people can enter it and buy the product. I will make sure the password is not something the bot can just copy and paste, you'll have to put in minimal effort to work it out - but will be very difficult for a computer to do on its own.

The main issue I see with this is that the way I have implemented it is when they go to the password page and submit the password, if they enter the correct password then I give them a cookie with the password in it. Then, when they try and access the purchase page I check the cookie and only let them in if the password is correct. This also applies to POSTing their payment information to my server. The problem is that once they have the password, they can simply enter it into a bot that will then check out a bunch of times. Or even quicker they can have one enter it then copy the cookie and give it to all the others and check out faster and more times than any human could.

I have implemented reCaptcha v2, but honestly that is trivial to bypass with a captcha harvester.

I thought about generating a session ID for each user when they initially visit the password page (will stay the same if they visit again), then when they purchase the product I store their ID in a database. Then, when someone is checking out I see if their ID is in the database already, and if it is then I stop the checkout. This probably solves the cookie sharing issue but doesn't solve getting the password and just checking out multiple times at once via different sessions using Python aiohttp or something.

Tying the cookie to an IP address in a similar way also crossed my mind, but this can be easily circumvented with the use of proxies.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can protect my website? I want my customers to be satisfied and so I would not like bots to be able to buy up all the stock before they can.

**EDIT:** Another thought was to still use a session ID, then store all session IDs and a boolean for whether or not they have checked out, such that it can be checked in the same way as before. However, I will also store a question ID along with the session ID. This question ID will represent a question that has been randomly selected from a dictionary of questions where the key is the ID and the value is the question and the answer. That way, provided I have enough questions and they aren't easy to solve with a bot, it will be very difficult for them to bot my site. An example of such a question could be "What is the URL of the most viewed video on YouTube?".

I realise all of this may seem unnecessary and like it's hurting the user but I think it is worth it.

**EDIT2:** What about reCaptcha v3? Is a reCaptcha v3 token verified in the same way as v2, i.e. can a v2 generated token using my domain (e.g. by using flask and changing the hosts file then making a captcha and generating tokens that way) be used instead of a v3 token even if my website is using v3, and Google will accept it?

Comment: Lemme get this straight?you want people to buy your stuff slowly?What difference would that even make?

Comment: This is effectively impossible.  The only solution is to charge more money.

Comment: @VipulNair Yes. I want normal customers to be able to purchase my product rather than people who have bots. I would like to make it difficult for people to purchase more than one product per release, which will be possible if I can make it difficult for bots to check out because it will have sold out by the time they try again.

Comment: @ConorMancone Effectively impossible maybe, but I'd appreciate some suggestions and answers to my questions.

Comment: Would you be able to rate limit checkouts based on IP address or credit card number?

Comment: @Daniel Easily circumvented by using proxies and Privacy cards.

Comment: "Easily", any layer of protection/security requires more effort. In the end, it's just a matter of who has the most resources/whether it's worth it for the attacker/buyer.

Comment: @Daniel That is trivial to circumvent, I'm at least looking for something more robust if not impenetrable. I would like to make it too annoying for people to develop a bot to check out on my website so they move onto another.

Comment: Excellent, I found the story I wanted...  Very relevant reading https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/mgxqb8/the-man-who-broke-ticketmaster

Comment: @ConorMancone An interesting read but as far as I can tell doesn't provide any solutions.

Comment: @JackP Indeed.  More the point is that there is a lot more to this than just bots.  They are one part of the puzzle, but the reality is that market forces are the most important part, and if you have something with enough value that people are willing to deploy an army of bots to get it, then they will always find another way to get in.

Comment: Jack P, You may want to have a look at Cloudflare's Bot Management solution.  See https://www.cloudflare.com/products/bot-management/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356806/get-final-url-after-timed-delay-or-redirect.